# Incorrect timezone in elasticsearch histogram aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a document with field 
`"creationDate": "2015-12-13T22:00:00.000+0300"`
the mapping for this field is:

```
"creationDate": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
}
```

I want to create histogram aggregation and format output date in exist format with this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "docs": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "creationDate": {
                  "gte": "2015-12-23T00:00:00+02:00",
                  "lte": "2015-12-23T23:59:59+02:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "deep": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "actions"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "histogram": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "actions.creationDate",
                "interval": "1h",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
                "time_zone": "+03:00"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But as result I get result in UTC format:

```
    {
    "key_as_string": "2015-12-13T19:00:00+0000",
    "key": 1450033200000,
    "doc_count": 1
    }
```

I don't understand why exist format transform to UTC and how can I get expected format? I thought that "time_zone" parameter should fix this issue but no

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Elasticsearch 1.x, as this seems to be an expected behavior that was improved in 2.x. Please, see this comment [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13236#issuecomment-138270229) and, also, the issue that adds this enhancement in the 2.x branch.